# VSCode - Regex to find string excluding others substrings

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I have a base classname form my icons, that is `i-svg` (this is the default icon size).

I have some modifiers to change the size, like `i-svg--xs` or `i-svg--sm`.

I need to find only the lines that don't use the modifiers classnames, that is just `i-svg`.

**Excluded searches**

```
class="someclass1 i-svg i-svg--xs someclass2"
class="someclass1 i-svg someclass2 i-svg--xs"
class="i-svg i-svg--xs"
class="i-svg i-svg--xs someclass1"
class="someclass1 i-svg i-svg--xs someclass2"
```

**Included searches**

```
class="someclass1 i-svg someclass2"
class="someclass1 i-svg"
class="i-svg someclass1"
class="i-svg"
```

What regular expression can I use for this search?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that `i-svg` is a prefix of the string not allowed

You can do it in a 2 step find

- Prepare a file with the following 2 regex strings

  ```
  class="[^"]*i-svg[^"]*"
  ^((?!i-svg--(xs|sm)).)*$
  ```

  Second regex based on [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/406408/9938317)
- select the first regex: `class="[^"]*i-svg[^"]*"`
- go to the file where you want to find
- search for `class="[^"]*i-svg[^"]*"`
- press `Alt+Enter` to select all matches and put focus in editor
- go to other file and pick up: `^((?!i-svg--(xs|sm)).)*$` with `Ctrl+C`
- go back to the file where you want to find
- in find dialog press button: **Find in Selection**
- replace regex with: `^((?!i-svg--(xs|sm)).)*$` with a `Ctrl+V`

Now only the class attributes with only `i-svg` are found.

Comment: Hi @rioV8, thanks for you quick response
unfortunately doesn't work ):